# What tag to parse BeautifulSoup to retrieve this number

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to identify the tag of this HTML code in order to parse it through Beautiful Soup and scrape just one number however I cannot identify which tag to use in order to obtain just this number.

The HTML code looks like this:

```html
<div style="font-size:88px;  color:#345C99;position:relative;top:56px;left:calc(6% - 46px)">6</div>
```

I am trying to obtain the `6` in this element `>6<`

Comment: You should probably post the `div` in context.  Otherwise it's going to be very hard for anyone to answer this for you.

Comment: What other HTML is on the page? Please [edit] your question to include some more of the HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
from bs4 import Beautiful Soup
s = '''<div style="font-size:88px;  color:#345C99;position:relative;top:56px;left:calc(6% - 46px)">6</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
d = soup.find('div')
print(d.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that `font-size:88px;` is peculiar enough to select the divs you want, so that

```
soup.select('div[style~="font-size:88px;"]')
```

should help you get all the divs in the page

Comment: And what if there are other elements with the same font size?

Comment: i think this is what he wants, if i'm wrong i'll delete the answer

Comment: The OP is looking to identify a specific tag on the page. Now, you have used a selector the finds all tags with a specific font size, if the _only_ HTML on the page was what the OP has provided, then your answer would be great, however, if there are multiple tags on the page with the same font size, your selector won't necessarily select the correct one. This answer might be correct, the OP would need to provide some more of the HTML

Comment: This is great! It is the only element with font size 88 so it works. Thanks a lot for that. I get the div element but how can I single out just the text element (6) from this now?

Comment: ram's answer does exactly that